# RAST 2.5 pcb design

Tags: pcb, connector, design, library

Currently I am designing a pcb and I need a RAST 2.5 connected to my board DIRECT MATING as seen as picture below (example from google).

[image: Example : the final product I expected]

But as I am searching in the library, I am using EAGLE, I couldn't find the exact component for that particular connector. I'm searching on google and couldn't find the right one. Anybody has the library for that component and kind enough to share it with me? 
DATASHEET : https://downloads.lumberg.com/datenblaetter/en/3521.pdf

Comment: Yes, that's the reason. Should i just put a wire ? and if so, what do I define in schematic layout ?

Comment: See my answer @azri

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The part: -

[image]

The part isn't a PCB solderable connector - it has wires on one end and sliding contacts on the other hence, why should there be a part for it in EAGLE or any PCB/schematic CAD package? It doesn't solder to the PCB cannot be regarded as having anything other than a schematic symbol - it can't have an EAGLE footprint because it has no solderable pins. Yes it might have wires connecting to it that get soldered to the PCB but, it won't have a footprint hence it will never be regarded as a valid component for EAGLE.

Comment: Thanks Andy. So I just draw a wire and it'll be done right ?

Comment: The only thing you'll have on your PCB schematic is a footprint for the pads (fingers) that this connector is going to mate with. You may need to create a custom part for that.

Comment: The wires leaving your board going to the connector can come from anywhere on that circuit board and so you could either arrange those wire solder points into a nice array of pads that can take the bare wires and be soldered or just randomly place pads (single point connections) anywhere on your PCB. If it's not too hard to do I'd try and keep the wires intact in-line and use an array. The array of pads can be a symbol/footprint.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I call an "edge connector" - the mating pattern on a PC board will just be some wide tracks at the edge of the PC board, spaced to match the contacts in the connector.

On the schematic, I would show a generic connector with the appropriate number of pins.  You will probably have to design the PCB footprint as shown in your first photo yourself.